# MYSQL View COUNT() not including zeros

Tags: mysql, view, count

I have two MySQL tables:

1. dpu_table
2. jobs_table

I created a view that would COUNT the number of rows that occur from a table in a column. The VIEW works great, other than it does not show zeros for instances that it did NOT count.

How would I display a count of zero?

Here are the tables:

[image]

Here's my SQL View:

```
CREATE VIEW `jobs_view` AS SELECT
`a`.`id`,
`a`.`jobnum`,
COUNT(`b`.`id`) AS `dpu_total` 
FROM `jobs_table` `a` 
INNER JOIN `dpu_table` `b` WHERE `a`.`id`=`b`.`jobnum_id` 
GROUP BY `b`.`jobnum_id`
```

This is what the view looks like:

[image]

I am missing the other job numbers. And I would like to display a "0" in the column for "dpu_total"

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the provided answer the trick was to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. I also had to substitute `WHERE` for `ON` and group by `jobs_table.id`. The new code is:

```
CREATE VIEW `jobs_view` AS SELECT
`a`.`id`,
`a`.`jobnum`,
COUNT(`b`.`id`) AS `dpu_total` 
FROM `jobs_table` `a` 
LEFT JOIN `dpu_table` `b` 
ON `a`.`id`=`b`.`jobnum_id` 
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN !

Comment: Left join worked. I also had to substitute the `WHERE` for `ON` in order for it to work. I will accept when the timer lets me.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer so it is not a suggestion of trying something but rather a piece of code with some explanation why it works. Although you are right this answer seems to me more like a comment.